# Magento upgrade 2.4.4, phpunit issue

Tags: magento2, phpunit, magento2.4.4, php8

I am getting below issue while upgrading to Magento version 2.4.4 on php 8

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.9 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.8 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.13 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.12 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.11 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.10 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.5.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.10, 6.5.11, 6.5.12, 6.5.13,
> 6.5.14, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7, 6.5.8, 6.5.9].

Do we need to upgrade the phpunit version manually?

Answer (score 5):

you need to find the "require-dev" in your magento root **composer.json** file

```
"require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.5.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~3.3.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.10.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.9.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "~1.2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~9.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    }
```

replace this code after you need just run **composer update** command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your outdated list of PHPUnit versions.
I believe only PHPUnit 9+ has PHP 8 compatibility
Try to clean up the composer cache by executing `composer clearcache`

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually update the version of **phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14** to  **"phpunit/phpunit": "^9"** in composer.json After then run below command:

**composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update**

**composer update**